# Viewing browser console.log output on a Samsung Galaxy Tab 2.0 7"

Tags: javascript, android, adb

I feel like I must be doing something wrong.  On most Android devices, I can view the output of console.log in a browser window by using `adb logcat`.  However, that doesn't seem to be the case with the Samsung Galaxy Tab 2.0 7".  On this device, I don't see any logs from the browser at all, even when I'm not filtering.  Is there something I have to do in order to get that output logged?

Comment: AFAIK some (vendor) browsers just don't send the log anywhere useful.  Perhaps write something custom in javascript?  There are bookmarklet solutions for remote debugging.

Comment: I know with older versions of Android, I was able to use `adb logcat` and it would output the console.log messages directly into the log.  In fact, I can do exactly that on the Acer Iconia Tab I have sitting here as well, but I don't seem to be able to do it with the Samsung.  I'd prefer not to break into the bookmark debugging if I don't have to.

Comment: It appears to be something vendor choose to leave out, rather than based on android version.  You could consider using an alternative browser for general development, but then you aren't testing on that device's default browser.  If you want to use a default browser that does not support this, you probably are going to have to resort to something clever.

Comment: I have the same problem on a Samsung Galaxy S2.

Comment: @gregers if you find a solution, please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't find a way to see the log messages through adb logcat, but you can always use Weinre. It's a script you insert/inject that let you get a light version of WebKit Dev Tools remotely from your browser. It doesn't have everything, but you get console, inspect and some other tools. Download here http://people.apache.org/~pmuellr/weinre/docs/latest/ or use the hosted version http://debug.phonegap.com/